# Applying classes conditionally - Not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I want to add a class to an element when a property is true:

```
<div class="row-wrap" ng-class="{row-wrap-animation: Resizing == false}">
```

The row-wrap-animation class is not applied correctly. I set the property $scope.Resizing = false right at the start and the class is not there.

Is there something wrong with the above syntax?

```
app.controller( 'PageLayoutController', function ( $scope )
{
    $scope.Resizing = false;
    ...
```

Comment: try row-wrap-animation : Resizing
Also check why app.controller function is having ($scope : any), Thats not a parameter

Comment: Sorry, that's typescript.. I'll remove that.

Comment: try row-wrap-animation : Resizing

Comment: When you use `-` in the name of a class, you have to put `'` like this `ng-class="{'row-wrap-animation': Resizing == false}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="row-wrap" ng-class="Resizing ? '' : 'row-wrap-animation'"></div>

ng-class="Resizing ? 'anything' : 'row-wrap-animation'"
//        property     if true         if false
```

Comment: I would like row-wrap to always be on the element. row-wrap-animation will be an additional class that is added.

Comment: you can leave that empty then.. `ng-class="Resizing ? '' : 'row-wrap-animation'"`

Comment: `ng-class="( NavigationMenuHidden || !MobileMode ) ? '': 'fade-out'"` does not seem to be working any ideas?